# Deploy Google Apps Script OAuth 2.0 Web App executing functions as owner (me) available to anyone (anonymous user)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, twitch-api

I am building a Twitch API integration within a Google Apps Script project. The idea is to allow users to authenticate the Twitch App through the web app portal. The authentication works and an access token is returned as I need when deploying the Web App as "Execute As: User Accessing the App". But not when the Apps Script Web App is deployed as "Execute As : Me", then it only works when used by me and not externally. The error thrown in the web app is "The state token is invalid or has expired. Please try again." So my question is there a way to augment the code in the OAuth Library for Apps Script to have stateTokens work for anonymous users? Or a way to simply remove the need for stateToken. The code breaks when removing state from params. [similiar issue here](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/issues/74)

I have tried removing the stateToken from the params in the source code, but the code breaks.